# AES-Rijndael 128 encryption in Java

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, cryptography

I have a snippet in PHP that encrypts a plain String using AES 128 encryption.

I have a problem to use this in Java as I do not have any experience on cryptography.

Take a look at the PHP snippet here:

```
function encrypt_text($decrypted)
{
    $thePassKey = "MY_KEY_SOME_GIBBERISH_KEY";

    # Add PKCS7 padding.
    $str = $decrypted;
    // Gets the block size of the specified cipher
    // MODE: CBC
    // CIPHER NAME: RIJNDAEL_128
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    
    echo "Encryption: ".MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128."<br/>";
    echo "Mcrypt Mode: ".MCRYPT_MODE_CBC."<br/>";
    echo "Block: " . $block."<br/>";

    if (($pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block)) < $block){
        $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }

    // Returns the size of the IV belonging to a specific cipher/mode combination
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

    $iv = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $iv_size; $i++){
        $iv .= "\0";
    }

    // mcrypt_encrypt: Encrypts plaintext with given parameters
    // base6_encode: Encodes data with MIME base64
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $thePassKey, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}
```

From the above snippet, I've managed to get the requirement it needs to encrypt a string which are:

> Encryption mode: rijndael-128
>
> Mcrypt mode: cbc
>
> Block: 16

So, how do I do exactly this but with Java? I'm implementing it in an android app, if that helps.

Comment: CBC with null IV is a horrible idea. It pretty much ruins the point of using CBC in the first place. Generate a random IV, use it, then prepend it to the message so that you can use it for decryption on the other side.

Comment: Is there any other alternative? I need to use the encryption internally from a class in java. Normally, i have to call the api each time I want to encrypt a text, which technically gives burden to memory management (doing Android). I have no power to change the code in the server side as I am not the back-end guy.

Comment: The back-end guy's code is wrong, so tell him to fix it. The "encryption" it performs is broken in two major ways. First, it uses a fixed null IV, instead of a random unique IV. Second, it doesn't perform any form of authenticity verification, which leaves you open to all sorts of nasty padding oracle issues and malleability attacks - the solution is to use something like HMAC-SHA256 to ensure the integrity and authenticity of the encrypted message.

Comment: This sort of encryption likely won't achieve what you're after ([see this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52584/why-can-we-still-crack-snapchat-photos-in-12-lines-of-ruby)).

Comment: Thank you for all of your information. I'll keep learning through this.